# Non-interference exact meaning in Java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Does the non-interference requirement for using streams of non-concurrent data structure sources mean that we can't change the state of an *element* of the data structure during the execution of a stream pipeline (in addition to that we can't change the source data structure itself)? (Question 1)

In the section about [non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), in the stream package description, its said: 
"For most data sources, preventing interference means ensuring that the data source is *not modified at all* during the execution of the stream pipeline."

This passage does not mention modifying the state of elements?

For example, assuming "shapes" is non-thread-safe collection (such as `ArrayList`), is the code below considered to have an interference? (Question 2)

```
shapes.stream() 
      .filter(s -> s.getColor() == BLUE)
      .forEach(s -> s.setColor(RED));
```

This example is taken from a [reliable source](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html) (to say the least), so it should be correct. 
But what if I changed `stream()` to be `parallelStream()`, will it still be safe and correct? (Question 3)

On the other hand, "Mastering Lambdas" by Naftalin Maurice, another reliable source, makes it clear that changing the state (value) of elements by the pipeline operation is indeed interference. From the section about non-interference (3.2.3):

"But the rules for streams forbid any modification of stream sources—including, for example, changing the value of an element— by any thread, not only pipeline operations."

If what's said in the book is correct, does it mean we can't use the Stream API to modify state of elements (using `forEach`), and have to do that using the regular iterator (or for-each, or `Iterable.forEach`)? (Question 4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a bigger class of functions called "functions with side effects". The JavaDoc statement is correct and complete: here interference means modifying the mutable source. Another case is stateful expressions: expressions which depend on the application state or change this state. You may read the [Parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#side_effects) tutorial on Oracle site.

In general you can modify the stream elements themselves and it should not be called as "interference". Beware though if you have the same mutable object produced several times by the stream source (for example, using `Collections.nCopies(10, new MyMutableObject()).parallelStream()`. While it's ensured that the same stream element is not processed concurrently by several threads, if your stream produces the same element twice, you may surely have a race condition when modifying it in the `forEach`, for example.

So while stateful expressions are sometimes smell and should be used with care and avoided if there's a stateless alternative, they are probably ok if they don't interfere with the stream source. When the stateless expression is required (for example, in [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method), it's specially mentioned in the API docs. In `forEach` documentation only non-interference is required.

So back to your questions:

Question 1: no we can change the element state, and it's not called interference (though called statefullness)

Question 2: no it has no interference unless you have repeating objects in your stream source)

Question 3: you can safely use `parallelStream()` there

Question 4: no, you can use Stream API in this case.

Comment: In other words, “interference” lives on a higher level. An action modifying a stream element can interfere, when it’s modifying the same element concurrently, but it doesn’t when it is modifying distinct objects. Similarly, an `ArrayList` not being thread safe on its own does not preclude the possibility of `ArrayList`s being used correctly in a concurrent scenario. It’s all about, *how* it is used…

Comment: Thanks Tagir for your clear and detailed answer. Maintaining modifiable elements in collections is common task, and many operations on collections that are done using iterator - need to change the elements state, so it really bothered me. It would have made streams much less useful if we couldn't safely do that (at least in the case of parallel streams).

Comment: Tagir, note that stateful lambda is defined in the stream package (and in the link you mentioned) as "one whose result depends on any state which might change during the execution of the stream pipeline".

Comment: Continue, premature enter :). It doesn't say anything about changing the state per se. So the lambda of the example I posted (s -> s.setColor(RED)) has side effect, but according to that definition - is not stateful...

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the state of an object stored in a data structure is different from reassigning an element of a data structure.

When the other writes "changing the value of an element" presumably they mean as if assigning a new object to an index of an existing `List`.

From your [link](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html):

> It is best to avoid any side-effects in the lambdas passed to stream methods. While some side-effects, such as debugging statements that print out values are usually safe, accessing mutable state from these lambdas can cause data races or surprising behavior since lambdas may be executed from many threads simultaneously, and may not see elements in their natural encounter order. Non-interference includes not only not interfering with the source, but not interfering with other lambdas; this sort of interference can arise when one lambda modifies mutable state and another lambda reads it.
>
> As long as the non-interference requirement is satisfied, we can execute parallel operations safely and with predictable results even on non-thread-safe sources such as ArrayList.

This pertains specifically to parallelism and is no different than any other concurrent programming. Modifying state can cause issues with visibility amongst threads.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tim. Specifically the quote you brought here made me feel more uncertain about modifying state of the elements of the stream source, because it legitimizes not-modifying side effects as "debugging statements that print out values". It doesn't confront directly with my issue.

Comment: I think the guidance is don't modify the state if your are doing parallel operations and will do more operations.